# Unknown server tag 'EPiServerUI:ToolButton'

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver-7

I'm using EPiServer 7 CMS. When trying to reach the back-office, I keep getting the `Unknown server tag 'EPiServerUI:ToolButton'.` error. I use IIS 7 and windows 7.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Register TagPrefix="EPiServerUI"
Namespace="EPiServer.UI.WebControls" Assembly="EPiServer" %> Line 2:  
Line 3:  <EPiServerUI:ToolButton CssClass="epi-cmsButton"
runat="server"/> Line 4:  <EPiServerUI:ToolButton SkinId="Add"
CssClass="epi-cmsButton" CssClassInnerButton="epi-cmsButton-tools
epi-cmsButton-Add" runat="server"/> Line 5:  <EPiServerUI:ToolButton
SkinId="AddFile" CssClass="epi-cmsButton"
CssClassInnerButton="epi-cmsButton-tools epi-cmsButton-AddFile"
runat="server"/>

Source File: /App_Themes/Default/ToolButton.skin    Line: 3
```

I tried repairing .net framework with

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

but it didn't help.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In web.config
under <pages...><controls> in that file

add

<add tagPrefix="EPiServerUI" namespace="EPiServer.UI.WebControls" assembly="EPiServer.UI" />